# Как отключить автопросмотр PDF и как скачать файл без подтверждения в Firefox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Браузер инициализируется следующим образом:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
            options = FirefoxOptions()
            profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
            profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
            profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
            profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", True)
            profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "" + dwnld_path + "")
            profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,application/msword,text/csv")

self.wd = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, capabilities={"marionette": True}, executable_path="" + wd_path + "/geckodriver.exe",
                                            firefox_binary="C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox 60/firefox.exe")
```

Но, тем не менее, при загрузке файла все равно появляется диалоговое окно, с которым ничего не происходит.

Отсюда возник вопрос: а Firefox вообще может сохранять файлы, которые скачиваются не по ссылке, а подсовываются через JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

дело оказалось в настройке по умолчанию "Предпросмотр PDF", что решилось дополнительной преференсой:

```
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
```

Comment: Измените название и текст вопроса, так, что-бы другой человек смог найти его, если будет искать как отключить автопросмотр PDF, и как скачать файл без подтверждения. А так-же отметьте свой ответ как принятый.

Comment: Спасибо, заголовок обновил... а вот, чтобы отметить решением, нужно еще 2 часа ждать)

Comment: Вам спасибо)) Одним полезным ответом больше))))